# Can I marry Carlotta Valentia in Skyrim and if so, how?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I really want to marry Carlotta Valentia.

I have the Amulet of Mara and I have completed her quest. Then what?

Is there anything I'm missing?. I can't find anything on the internet or at Skyrim wiki.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

She's not on the list of potential spouses at http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim%3aMarriage, so that means no, it is not possible to marry her.

Comment: You can by using the console... If RustyMembers is desperate, this is a solution!

Comment: Sounds like a forced marriage to me. She'll never be happy. I bet she won't even share her store profits with you.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a pc it's

```
addfac 19809 1
```

Through the console (adds selected NPC to the marriage faction).
Might be glitchy, but probably not with Caroletta.

Answer (score -1):

I can actually marry her. I wore the amulet of mara. then when I talked to her, she said something like'is that the amulet of mara? 'Then there is also an option saying 'interested in me, are you?' I dont know if its just me, and no, I did not use the console command.

Comment: Any mods you have installed that might have allowed that?

Answer (score -1):

You cannot marry her. I have tried, but she just says no, but I recommend marrying Aela the Huntress